# Event listener from parent window to 2 levels nested iframe possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, addeventlistener, postmessage

[image: green box my web app / orange box iframe app / red box 3rd party web app through iframe]

I have a form on a web page (green box) that is supposed to submit data on my backend system.
I have also a web app (orange box) that i have control of in terms of source code, which contains a third party form through an iframe (red box).
The red box is a form with a submit button.

The request is on submitting form in red box, to submit the form in the green box.
I have accomplished that through event listener postmessage transferring neccessary data from the red box to the green.
The problem is that i want to prevent red box submission, if the fields in green box are empty.
I thought to apply an overlay div transparent on top of red box that will be removed on filling the green boxes, but i m not really happy with this idea.
Could this be handled through javascript?
I have control of green and orange window / documents but not red

Comment: as soon as the content of an iframe is not in your origin you will not even be able to figure out its URL after loading it. the purpose of this has to do with security.

Comment: my concern hasn't to do with the url.. it has to do with preventing form submission if my form is empty

Comment: let me be clear: if you are not even able to figure out the URL of the frame, you will most likely not be able to do anything else with that frame. well you can resize it but thats all you can do. this is a wanted security aspect to prevent phishing. if you want to find a way around this you should eather put the form onto your server or read about secure iframes.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is a sandboxed iframe. for more details follow this link:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: i look a little bit further on sandbox attribute, the first idea was javascript, but due to cross domain restrictions is not possible..hope i ll be luckier with sandbox attribute